# Why do we write the expression in a different manner?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose, we are given to factor a polynomial $P(x) = 54x^4 + 27x^3a - 16x - 8a$. Here, $P(- \frac{a}{2}) = 0$, hence, $x - (- \frac{a}{2})$ or $(x + \frac{a}{2})$ will be a factor of $P(x)$. But, when we get that for $x = -\frac{a}{2}$ the polynomial becomes $0$, we transform the equation as $2x+a = 0$ and state that $2x+a$ will be a factor of $P(x)$. But why do we do so, that is my question.

Answer (score 1):

In $\Bbb Q[x]$ and in $\Bbb Z[x]$ the polynomial is reducible and we have the factorization
$$
P(x)= (2x+a)(9x^2 + 6x + 4)(3x - 2).
$$
So indeed $2x+a$ is a factor. Of course, then every multiple
is also a factor, for example $x+\frac{a}{2}$ or $\frac{x}{2}+\frac{a}{4}$. If $a$ is an odd integer, and we want to view the factors in $\Bbb Z[x]$, then
we chose the factor $2x+a$, in order to have integer coefficients. The same applies for the factor $3x-2$, where we also have that $x-\frac{2}{3}$ is a factor.

Comment: Ok, I think I am getting the answer. Does it mean that if we use $x + \frac{a}{2}$ as the factor, we can still factorise the polynomial, but we won't get the integer coeffecients?

Comment: Yes. Take the polynomial $f(x)=2x+a$ itself. We could write it as $f(x)=2(x+\frac{a}{2})$, but the factor $x+\frac{a}{2}$ doesn't have integer coefficients in general. On the other hand it is monic, i..e, has leading coefficient $1$.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer you can accept it.